# I lost my keyfile. Is it possible to access my account again?

Tags: accounts

I lost my account's keyfile. Is it somehow possible to access it again?

Comment: define "lost" How did you lose it, what type of OS do you have?

Comment: I formatted my ssd.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Which client did you use, geth?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux for how to recover files.

Comment: I was using geth.

Thanks for the answers, I'll try to restore the files of the ssd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you participated in the geneses pre-sale and if this keyfile was generated as a result of `geth wallet import` you can import it again using the same command.

If not take your HDD to a shop that specialises in disk content recovery. That is, of course, if you didn't zero out the contents of the disk.

EDIT: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/can-wiped-ssd-data-be-recovered